# Raspberry Pi 4B does not detect USB storage devices

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi4

I tried plugging two flash drives into a Raspberry Pi 4B one after another but the Pi does not seem to detect any of the drives. Here is the dmesg output

```
[ 177.737328] cpu cpu0: dev_pm_opp_set_rate: failed to find current OPP for freq 4294967186 (-34) 
[ 180.446246] raspberrypi-clk soc:firmware:clocks: Failed to change fw-clk-arm frequency: -110 
[ 181.036364] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110 
[ 181.052412] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110 
[ 181.052421] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead 
[ 181.052446] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up [ 181.052645] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command 
[ 181.053349] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2 
[ 181.536432] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 5, error -108 
[ 181.536608] usb 1-1-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

USB problems in RPi typically happens because of a corrupted kernel, try to update it then give me a feedback.

Comment: How can I check for that. Should I just reinstall the kernal image

Comment: just update your raspebien using sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade, if this didn't work, you might need to manually install an older kernel version.

Comment: I tried rpi-update as well as reinstalling the kernal. But it didn't solve the problem